# How to Fix WHERE Clause in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, where-clause

I have an issue with Laravel Eloquent when using a WHERE clause.

**Code**

```
<?php

$locale = Session::get('locale');

$categories = Category::whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($locale) {
    $query->where('locale', $locale);
})->get();
```

**Generated SQL**

```
select * from `categories` 
    where exists (select * from `category_translations`
        where `category_translations`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` 
        and **`locale` = ?**)
```

It does not register the given value for `locale`.

I'm also getting the same issue if I put `->where('locale', 'en')`, and even if I try a raw query instead of using Eloquent model.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you tried to print_r($locale) and check if it has any value or not

Comment: ->toSql() won't return variable binding

Comment: @SR_ Thank you @

Comment: @Exprator $locale is not empty, as I already mentioned even ->where('locale', 'en') returns no results. If I try the sql in mysql it gives me the desired list, but not the query in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Like SR_ wrote in the comment toSql() function doesn't return variable binding. If you would like to see how the real queries looks like you can install tools like Laravel Debugar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Thanks. I understood that toSql() wont return the variable binding, but the way I write the same sql (that should be generated) in mysql I get the filtered list, not in Laravel